# Using algebra to figure out how many boxes fit in an area without over estimating

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, ceiling-and-floor-functions, packing-problem

I'm trying to figure out how many boxes fit in a specific area without over-estimating. The problem is the width of the space isn't a whole number multiple of the width of the boxes, the depth isn't either, nor the height.

[image]

I could estimate by just divide the width of the area by the width of the box, and multiply that by the hight of the area divided by the hight of the box, but as you can imagine I might end up with more boxes than I can fit in the area. (mainly because all the "extra space" adds up to being several boxes in volume).

Is there an algebraic way of getting around this? I know I could use the floor and ceiling function and write a computer program to figure it out, but this feels like this should be solvable using algebra alone. Thanks

Comment: Are the boxes required to be in that orientation? If not, are they required to to have their faces parallel to the larger box's?

Comment: Yeah this is the requird orientation.

Comment: This problem is similar somewhat to: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1622285/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-boxes-that-can-fit-in-a-rectangular-container

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the smaller boxes must all have the orientation shown, the count is
$$
\left\lfloor\frac{w_s}{w_b}\right\rfloor
\left\lfloor\frac{h_s}{h_b}\right\rfloor
\left\lfloor\frac{d_s}{d_b}\right\rfloor
$$

Comment: I've never seen this format before. I'm guessing this works similar to the way the square route of some number works, or the log, where we write it out using some made up syntax and throw it at a computer to parse and use an algorithm to solve?

Comment: The [floor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) (also known as greatest integer function) is built-in to most computer languages, but you don't need a computer to use it.  Just do the division and throw away the remainder.

Comment: The frustration I have with maths sometimes is overwhelming. I don't understand how it can be acceptable to make a syntax up and delegate the problem to another field. It's like me saying y = x (where x has a smiley face above it), and x is reducable "Ah, the smile function, that *is* the answer to the problem, you need not simplify x further just pass the smile-ed x to the computer and it will solve it! - or do it yourself!" - I feel like people would be up in arms if the smile function gained traction.

Comment: Rant aside - thanks for your answer, you never made maths this way :)!